# Bootstrap 4 containers grid error while compiling scss

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, media-queries

I'm trying to get only the containers grid from bootstrap4 grid system but I have an error on compiling and I really don't understand why :|

so this is the my custom scss file:

```
$grid-gutter-width:           30px !default;
$enable-grid-classes:       true !default;

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
) !default;

@mixin make-container() {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: ($grid-gutter-width / 2);
  padding-left: ($grid-gutter-width / 2);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

// Media of at least the minimum breakpoint width. No query for the smallest breakpoint.
// Makes the @content apply to the given breakpoint and wider.
@mixin media-breakpoint-up($name, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  $min: breakpoint-min($name, $breakpoints);
  @if $min {
    @media (min-width: $min) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    @content;
  }
}

// For each breakpoint, define the maximum width of the container in a media query
@mixin make-container-max-widths($max-widths: $container-max-widths, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  @each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $max-widths {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
      max-width: $container-max-width;
    }
  }
}

@if $enable-grid-classes {
  .container {
    @include make-container();
    @include make-container-max-widths();
  }
}

@if $enable-grid-classes {
  .container-fluid {
    @include make-container();
  }
}
```

and this is the error:

```
(xs: 0, sm: 576px, md: 768px, lg: 992px, xl: 1200px) isn't a valid CSS value.
```

This should be compiled in some media-queries with given variables but 
somewhere the movie is broken and ... so please give me a hint or something :|

I am using https://www.sassmeister.com/ for online compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Your sass is missing a required function `breakpoint-min` used in the `media-breakpoint-up` mixin. It's located in the `mixins/_breakpoints.scss` file around `line 26` of the latest Bootstrap source files (Nov/2018)

```
// Minimum breakpoint width. Null for the smallest (first) breakpoint.
//
//    >> breakpoint-min(sm, (xs: 0, sm: 576px, md: 768px, lg: 992px, xl: 1200px))
//    576px
@function breakpoint-min($name, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  $min: map-get($breakpoints, $name);
  @return if($min != 0, $min, null);
}
```

*You've likely already found out since 11 months ago but I'll leave it here for anyone else to know to carefully read copied code and check for any required or missing functions, variables or mixins.*

Here is the fixed code, I've test and works:

```
$grid-gutter-width:           30px !default;
$enable-grid-classes:       true !default;

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
) !default;

// Minimum breakpoint width. Null for the smallest (first) breakpoint.
//
//    >> breakpoint-min(sm, (xs: 0, sm: 576px, md: 768px, lg: 992px, xl: 1200px))
//    576px
@function breakpoint-min($name, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  $min: map-get($breakpoints, $name);
  @return if($min != 0, $min, null);
}

@mixin make-container() {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: ($grid-gutter-width / 2);
  padding-left: ($grid-gutter-width / 2);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

// Media of at least the minimum breakpoint width. No query for the smallest breakpoint.
// Makes the @content apply to the given breakpoint and wider.
@mixin media-breakpoint-up($name, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  $min: breakpoint-min($name, $breakpoints);
  @if $min {
    @media (min-width: $min) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    @content;
  }
}

// For each breakpoint, define the maximum width of the container in a media query
@mixin make-container-max-widths($max-widths: $container-max-widths, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  @each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $max-widths {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
      max-width: $container-max-width;
    }
  }
}

@if $enable-grid-classes {
  .container {
    @include make-container();
    @include make-container-max-widths();
  }
}

@if $enable-grid-classes {
  .container-fluid {
    @include make-container();
  }
}
```